# multiple entry of products in the database - PHP

Tags: php, forms

I explain briefly I created a table that shows all my products on video, where inside the container that contains it are two select, enclosed in a form, which pass values ​​in order to populate the table in my db, and everything works perfectly. The only thing though that when I select more than one product the db correctly registers only the last one selected from the checkbox,place my code in order to reach my goal, that of being able to insert more products(impianto_id_campagna),for the same customer id (cliente_id_campagna), and event id (id_campagna_cliente):

code:

```
<?php
$messaggio = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include '../connessione.php';
$id_campagna_cliente = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['id_campagna_cliente']);
$cliente_id_campagna = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['cliente_id_campagna']);
$impianto_id_campagna = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['impianto_id_campagna']);
$connessione->query("INSERT INTO campagne_cliente (
id_campagna_cliente,
cliente_id_campagna,
impianto_id_campagna) 

VALUES (
'$id_campagna_cliente', 
'$cliente_id_campagna', 
'$impianto_id_campagna')");
$messaggio = "Registrazione Completata!";
}
?>      

 <main>
<?php
include '../connessione.php';
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM store_locator WHERE store_locator.id NOT IN (SELECT impianto_id_campagna FROM campagne_cliente)";
$query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
?>

<?php
include '../connessione.php';
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM clienti";
$clienti = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
?>

<?php
include '../connessione.php';
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM campagne_cliente
INNER JOIN clienti
ON clienti.cliente_id = campagne_cliente.cliente_id_campagna 
INNER JOIN campagne
ON campagne.id_campagna = campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente GROUP BY cognome";
$campagne = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
?>


<!-- Datatables initialization -->
<script>
// Basic example
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
</script>

<!-- Structured data: Breadcrumbs -->



<form method="post" action="index.php">
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6">
<select name="cliente_id_campagna" class="ciao colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Cerca il Cliente">
<option value="" disabled selected>Cliente</option>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($clienti)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['cliente_id'] ;?>"><?php echo $row['nome'].'&nbsp;'.$row['cognome'] ;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Material Select Initialization
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ciao').material_select();
});
</script>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<select name="id_campagna_cliente" class="ok colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Cerca la campagna">
<option value="" disabled selected>Cliente</option>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($campagne)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id_campagna_cliente'] ;?>"><?php echo $row['nome'].'&nbsp;'.$row['cognome'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;INIZIO['.$row['data_inizio'].']&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FINE['.$row['data_fine'].']' ;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Material Select Initialization
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ok').material_select();
});
</script>
</div>

</div>


<div  class="col-md-12">
<?php if ($messaggio != "") echo $messaggio . "<br><br>"; ?>

<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th-sm">ID
        <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Cimasa
        <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Proprietaria
        <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Concessionaria
        <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">City
        <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Latitudine
        <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Longitudine
        <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>
<tr>
<td>        
<!-- Material unchecked -->
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" name="impianto_id_campagna" class="form-check-input" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"></label>
</div>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row['cimasa'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['proprietaria'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['concessionaria'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['city'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['lat'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['lng'] ;?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>


  </tfoot>
</table>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Register..."><br>


</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It register only the last one selected product because you have the same name attribute for every checkbox. Set the name to `impianto_id_campagna[]` in order to return an array in your `$_POST` variable.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="impianto_id_campagna[]" class="form-check-input" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">
```

Then you loop all your checkbox values inserting one product at a time:

```
<?php
$id_campagna_cliente = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['id_campagna_cliente']);
$cliente_id_campagna = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['cliente_id_campagna']);

foreach ($_POST['impianto_id_campagna'] as $value)
{
    $impianto_id_campagna = $connessione->real_escape_string($value);

    $connessione->query("INSERT INTO campagne_cliente (
    id_campagna_cliente,
    cliente_id_campagna,
    impianto_id_campagna) 

    VALUES (
    '$id_campagna_cliente', 
    '$cliente_id_campagna', 
    '$impianto_id_campagna')");

    $messaggio = "Registrazione Completata!";
}
```

Comment: Try now, I had entered the wrong `$_POST` variable in the loop.

Comment: YEEEEEESSSS SIRRRRRRR WOOOOOOOORK, THANK YOU SO MUCHHHHHH FOR SPENDING YOUR TIME WITH ME, THANKS A LOT SIR

Comment: o meglio ora che ho visto che sei di reggio emilia, grazie mille per il tuo aiuto, lo apprezzo davvero

Answer (score -1):

Checkbox items are passed as an array. In order to get them in to the database, you have to loop through the array and act accordingly.

```
foreach($impianto_id_campagna as $row){
    //Iterate through and do what you need to do with the data.
}
```

Comment: how to write php and html, in the same mode, to my code for while?

Comment: You can escape out of PHP and in to HTML any time with the php closing tag.
<p>This is raw HTML</p> <?php echo "This is php";?> <p>This is more raw HTML</p>

Comment: <?php foreach($impianto_id_campagna as $row): ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="impianto_id_campagna" class="form-check-input" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">
<label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"></label>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: but now i can't see my checkbox :/

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your goal. Please clarify your question.